# Is it possible to import a function in a modules subfolder

Tags: node.js, import

I'm trying to access the `decode()` method in the jsQR module.

I found an example that called `decode()` directly but that was from an HTML file, not nodejs.

In visual code I see this...

[image]

I know that the default export is defined in `index.d.ts` but is there anyway of importing the other classes/functions on the rest of the `dist` folder?

I've tried to import using `require("jsqr/decoder")` and `require("jsqr/decoder/decode")` to no avail.

**EDIT**

To be clear, I don't want `jsQR`, the default export. That deals with images. I'm trying to explicitly call the `decode()` method in the pic which accepts a `BitMatrix`

Answer (score 0):

There are no limitations in what you can require from `node_modules`. So, with your case it should look like:

*TypeScript\ESM Modules:*

```
import { decode } from 'jsqr/dist/decoder/decoder';
```

*CommonJS:*

```
const { decode } = require('jsqr/dist/decoder/decoder');
```

---

**UPD:** If you take a look into `dist` [folder](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR/tree/master/dist/decoder) for `jsqr` package, you can find that there are only `d.ts` files. Which means that you can not import it from there.

But, you can find an actual export of the module [here](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR/blob/master/dist/jsQR.js#L815):

Which means that you should able to import it from `jsqr`:

```
const { decode } = require('jsqr');
```

Comment: gives me ... `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: That's the first thing i tried when I got the error :) that doesn't work either.

Comment: Well then it means that there is no file in there, or no function called `decode`. Check that **you have an actual implementation of the function in the file**, not just typings.

Comment: I don't know anything about how `node_modules` works. In the image I shared I can see file `/node_modules/jsqr/dist/decoder/decoder.d.ts` which contains method declaration `export declare function decode` so I was hoping I could import/reference/etc. this method.

Comment: `d.ts` files store type information only. These files don't have an implementation. These are like `.h` files in C. Look for `.ts` or `.js` files, these are have an implementation you are looking for.